# Parsing site HTML instead of API

Tags: html, parsing, mobile, web-scraping

I'm in the process of making an app and wondered if it is bad practice to parse a website's HTML page (in terms of efficiency) when their API does not provide me with the specific information I need for an element in my app. (Of course all due credit/sources will be provided visibly in my app, etc, etc)

For instance: if for some reason the Google Places API does not provide me with a venue's business hours, so as a workaround I go to that venue's Google Places page and parse the HTML for that business' hours to place in my app.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad and asks about the legal validity of something, which would be better suited for an attorney.

Comment: You ask if something is valid without showing research effort. Plus, this would probably be complicated to explain. You would need to talk about what laws allow/prevent it and in what ways it would be efficient/inefficient, which could become a very large answer.

Comment: On a side note, it could also be considered primarily opinion based: *wondered if it is bad practice*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some thoughts that I hope would make things clearer.

If an API doesn't provide the data you need, first, a good idea would be to contact the API developers and request the functionality you need. Also, before taking the web-scraping/html-parsing approach you have to study the legal side of it, make sure the web-site is not against web-scraping - study `Terms of Use`.

Also, take into account the possible complexity of the html-parsing code. You would depend on the actual HTML markup that can be changed at any point. The solution you would implement can be really fragile because of it.

Besides, some things can be very difficult to get without a real browser. For example, something can be calculated via a javascript code being executed in the browser, or via a set of complicated AJAX calls. In this case, you would need to utilize a real browser, which is, first, a dependency, and, second, the thing that would slow things down dramatically.

Besides, some sites have anti-web-crawling solutions in action, like banning the IP address after multiple consequent requests, or requiring a certain header to be sent with each request etc.

You can also take another defensive step: contact the webmaster and discuss the problem.

Follow-up: [Web scraping etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette).